# What is the "key" for Quicksort

Tags: c, algorithm, quicksort

My Professor uses the term `key comparison` when talking about `quicksort`, but didn't explain what exactly the key is. If we're sorting an array of numbers, is a key a number in the array?

Comment: Instead of comparing objects in the array directly, you can apply a key function first and compare the results of those when applied to the objects in the array

Comment: key is the number on which sorting is done

Comment: Key is some characteristics of an object. It can be the object itself (the simplest case, used for educational examples with numbers), a part of object, a result of a function on the object, etc.

Comment: don't understand why this question is unclear and received four downvotes. seems like I received a perfectly legitimate answer for a perfectly legitimate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is whatever you're sorting on.

If you're just doing a typical sort of an array of numbers, then the key is a number.

If you're sorting, for example, objects describing people, and you're sorting this by their surname, then the key would be the surname.